# UWP Numeric Password Box

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I know that UWP currently has Password Box control, but this control does not have InputScope property, so it causes a lot of problems. For that purposes in my application I wrote down my custom control. 
But, yesterday, while looking through a setting in my NL 930 (windows 10, build 10568), I found that interesting thing inside the SIM settings (this is system application).
So, as you can see here, there is typical Password Box with "PIN" InputScope. Maybe there exists a control about which I don't know?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PasswordBox` does have the `InputScope`. The control is introduced in the 10240 build. In the example of the `InputScope` it even uses the `NumericPin` value. Please check the installed build versions and the settings of your project. If you set the minimal version to low it the property might not show.

**Example from MSDN**

```
<PasswordBox>
  <PasswordBox.InputScope>
    <InputScope>
      <InputScope.Names>
        <InputScopeName NameValue="inputScopeName"/>
      </InputScope.Names>
    </InputScope>
  </PasswordBox.InputScope>
</PasswordBox>
```

MSDN PasswordBox
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227519

MSDN PasswordBox.InputScope
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.inputscope

Comment: Omg! It works! I know about that MSDN reference, but I tried that like the following: <PasswordBox InputScope="NumericPin" /> and it underlines it with the blue line. That's why I thought this is still not available... Anyway, thanks you very much!

Answer (score 4):

```
        <PasswordBox PlaceholderText="Enter PIN">
            <PasswordBox.InputScope>
                <InputScope>
                    <InputScope.Names>
                        <InputScopeName NameValue="NumericPin"/>
                    </InputScope.Names>
                </InputScope>
            </PasswordBox.InputScope>
        </PasswordBox>
```